# R: How to use append = TRUE but also delete existing file

Tags: r, csv, append, write.table

I have a for loop that loops through files and creates a giant CSV file by appending all the different data frames. 
For this to work I have used

```
append= TRUE
```

However, since I used that, if i run the loop again, it just appends the same thing to the file before.
I was wondering if there is a way I can tell the code to delete any file with that name before running the loop, so it does not append to old data.
This is the write.table code I have right now

```
write.table(dat, "data.csv", append = TRUE, sep = ",", col.names=!file.exists("data.csv"))
```

Comment: Could you use `append = (i > 1)`? (assuming `i` is your index)

Answer (score 3):

How about this in front of the loop?

```
if (file.exists("[yourfilename]"){
    unlink("[yourfilename]")
}
```